# How to keep the newest element of a numpy array each time this appear

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

when I print list I get this result and I just want to get the latest value

```
print (list)

([[ 0],
 [ 0, 6],
 [0, 6, 12],
 [0, 6, 12, 18]
.
.
.
 [0, 6, 12, 18, ... , n]
])

But I want it to be like this

[0, 6, 12, 18, ... , n]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't call it ```list```, let's call it ```a``` then ```a[-1]```.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly don't name your variable `list`, as it is a keyword.

And now the solution to your problem

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4],[2,5,4,7]]
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 4, 7]]
>>> print(l[-1])
[2, 5, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest element of a python list with the index `-1`, like:

```
mylist = [
 [0],
 [0, 6],
 [0, 6, 12],
 [0, 6, 12, 18],
 [0, 6, 12, 18, 19]
 ]

print(mylist[-1])
```

**Out:**

```
[0, 6, 12, 18, 19]
```

See: [What are negative indexes and why are they used?](https://www.i2tutorials.com/technology/what-are-negative-indexes-and-why-are-they-used/) or [index operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/indexing.html)

> Python programming language supports negative indexing of arrays,
>   something which is not available in arrays in most other programming
>   languages. This means that the index value of -1 gives the last
>   element, and -2 gives the second last element of an array. The
>   negative indexing starts from where the array ends. This means that
>   the last element of the array is the first element in the negative
>   indexing which is -1.

So with your example with e.g. `-2`:

```
    mylist = [
     [0],
     [0, 6],
     [0, 6, 12],
     [0, 6, 12, 18],
     [0, 6, 12, 18, 19]
     ]

    print(mylist[-2])
```

**Out:**

```
    [0, 6, 12, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all ... after posting this I went sleep and realized that I just had to take the last element as you all did. I should think twice next time before posting. I feel so ridiculous now. Anyway Thks.